# Как подключить нейронную сеть к веб-приложению?

Tags: веб-программирование, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

У меня есть: обученная нейронная сеть для классификации изображений на Py (h5) и веб-приложение на TypeScript. Приложение еще пока не задеплоено, но если это срочно необходимо для реализации задачи, то я сделаю это.
Что мне нужно: мне нужно подключить нейронную сеть к веб-приложению.
Как я предполагаю как это должно работать: пользователь заходит на сайт, загружает картинку, нейронка получает это изображение, классифицирует и отправляет результат классификации.
Как это сделать я, к сожалению, не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: У Вас же клиент-сервер, правильно? В таком случае грузите свою нейронку куда-то в папки сервера (к примеру в resources, но совсем не обязательно). Дальше нужно наладить работу с нейронкой. Если используете сторонний формат нейронных сетей, то ищите библиотеки под Ваш серверный язык и работающие с данным форматом.

Comment: К сожалению ничего более конкретного не посоветую. Гуглите или тупо ждите ответа. Лучше первое

Comment: получилось решить эту проблему?
Если да, подскажи как, пожалуйста.